# Sorting List of lists/ Arraylists/ Hashmaps with multiple values in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I want to create a table like structure in Java as shown in the image

Table structure
[image]
Though I am not an expert in Java, I have tried to implement it using Arraylist structure as follows:

```
List<List<Double>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
    List<Double> tempList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    dataList.add(tempList);
}

for(int y = 0; y < n; y++){
    double execution = exectime[y];
    double cost= cost[y];
    dataList.get(y).add(execution);
    dataList.get(y).add(cost);
}

for (int z=0;z<dataList.size();z++) {
    Double v1=dataList.get(z).get(0);
    Double v2=dataList.get(z).get(1);

    System.out.println("ID"+z +" Execution time:" + v1 + "cost: " + v2);
}
```

Where the values of 'n', 'exectime[n]' and 'cost[n]' will be read from a file and 'n' is the total number of 'ids' that needs to be created.

After creating the table, I want to sort it based on the 'execution time' value and 'cost' value, both increasing and decreasing order. Please help me in this regards.

Comment: please review your Edits done by a StackOverflow User first.

Comment: Have you ever tried a `Comparetor` Class to sort Custom classes? If it is So then only I will Help you out. @Nilotpal

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I have used a bit of it. Comparator.sort() method

Comment: what kind of confusion there ?? Its Very easy you may go through various examples on Internet.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@snovelli's answer about using a class to encapsulate your data is a good point.

If you are using Java 8, you can easily create and chain comparators that use accessors.

For sorting a list of objects, it might look something like:

```
List<ExecutionTimeData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(ExecutionTimeData::getExecutionTime)
    .thenComparing(ExecutionTimeData::getCost));
```

Sorting by execution time, followed by cost.

You could also use this to sort a `List<List<Double>>` if you really wanted to.

```
List<List<Double>> doubleListList = new ArrayList<>();
doubleListList.sort(Comparator
    .comparing((List<Double> l) -> l.get(0))
    .thenComparing(l -> l.get(1)));
```

Sorting by element 0 of the list, followed by element 1.

Or for sorting in reverse order:

```
List<ExecutionTimeData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(ExecutionTimeData::getExecutionTime).reversed()
    .thenComparing(ExecutionTimeData::getCost).reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use Collections as List < RegisterType > , RegisterType is created according to the type of registers present in the table (ex: with 3 double atributes)
- Implement the Comparator interface Comparator< RegisterType >
- Override the compare( RegisterType o1, RegisterType o2) method the way you want (define how to sort 2 elements of type RegisterType)
- Inkove Collections.sort(List< RegisterType > list, ComparatorClass)

Then you will have your collection list sorted the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

### A table is a way to represent a list of objects, why not use a list of object then?

I think you want to have a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) of a class that you could define as:

```
public class ExecutionTimeData{

    private final long id;
    private final long executionTime;
    private final int cost;

    public ExecutionTimeData(long id, long executionTime, int cost){
         this.id = id;
         this.executionTime = executionTime;
         this.cost = cost;
    }        

    /* Getters */      
   
}
```

Then you will simply have an unsorted list like

```
List<ExecutionTimeData> unsortedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

As pointed out from @VikrantKashyap to order the list with both value and cost you then must implement a [Chained Comparator](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example)

```
public class ExecutionTimeDataChainedComparator implements Comparator<ExecutionTimeData> {
 
    private List<Comparator<ExecutionTimeData>> listComparators;
 
    @SafeVarargs
    public ExecutionTimeDataChainedComparator (Comparator<ExecutionTimeData>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int compare(ExecutionTimeData etd1, ExecutionTimeData etd2) {
        for (Comparator<ExecutionTimeData> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(etd1, etd2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And implement the comparators like this

```
public class ExecutionTimeDataCostComparator implements Comparator<ExecutionTimeData > {
 
    @Override
    public int compare(ExecutionTimeData a, ExecutionTimeData b) {
       return b.getCost() > a.getCost()?-1:1;
    }
}

public class ExecutionTimeDataExecutionComparator implements Comparator<ExecutionTimeData > {
 
    @Override
    public int compare(ExecutionTimeData a, ExecutionTimeData b) {
       return b.getExecutionTime() > a.getExecutionTime()?-1:1;
    }
}
```

And of course you can find out an easy way to invert the order by instantiating the comparators providing `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` order

Comment: solution you have provided is not for Chained Comaparator . Its a Individual `Comparator` implementation . So It will always sort Individually not as a Chained . Thanks

Comment: So, please remove your answer.. It really bothers the owner if he try this solution. Kindly Delete this. @snovelli

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.sort() with Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

However, you will loss your `ID` information because it is based on your index of the ArrayList. Therefore, if you use this method and want to keep you ID information, you need to `add()` ID to your ArrayList just like `execution` and `cost`.

```
Comparator<List<Double>> ORDER = new Comparator<List<Double>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Double> lhs, List<Double> rhs) {
        if (lhs.get(1) < rhs.get(1)) return -1;
        if (lhs.get(1) == rhs.get(1)) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};

Collections.sort(dataList, ORDER);
```

In above code, your dataList will sorted with `cost`, because it is at the index 1 of the ArrayList.

However, the better way (in readability) is you put your column into a Class, not just a ArrayList. For example, you can create a Class like this:

```
class Information {
    private int id;
    private double execution;
    private double cost;

    Information(int id, double execution, double cost) {
        this.id = id;
        this.execution = execution;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

And implement static Comparator inside that class. It will improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use a Chained `Comparator` to implement `sorting` using multiple attributes. Because If you use a single `Comparator` Individually It will sort the data according to its own `Compare()` Method Implementation.

> Better to Go with Chained `Comparator` which sort your data on multiple attribute ... Try the Following Link   ==> [Sorting a list by multiple attributes example](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example)

Comment: No appriciation.. If it helped you kindly accept this as a answer or any up-vote or down-vote for this. Thanks @NilotpalChakraborty